# Browsers permission opened from app (Using javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, permissions, user-experience

All browsers require permissions to open camera, microphone, pop up windows,etc. Can you open the permission window from your app (Using javascript)? or only the browser can do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCLya.png)

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are asking, is this an android app / ios app? When using an app the user will still have to consent to the permissions and they will pop up for example if you have the permissions in your Android Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From mdn:

The `MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` method prompts the user for permission to use a media input which produces a MediaStream with tracks containing the requested types of media.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia